# How to copy KD-Tree CGAL

Tags: c++, pointers, copy-constructor, cgal, kdtree

I am new to CGAL, I need to construct a dynamic number of Neighbor_search::Tree based on provided point cloud. Here is sample code:

```
typedef Neighbor_search::Tree SpatialTree; 

std::vector<SpatialTree> cloudTrees(pointCloudPath.size()); 

for(int i = 0; i < pointCloudPath.size(); i++) 
{ 
        readPLY(pointCloudPath.at(i), pointClouds.at(i));   
        SpatialTree cloudtree(pointClouds.at(i).begin(), pointClouds.at(i).end()); 
        cloudTrees.at(i) = cloud1tree; //error 
}
```

I am getting error: 'boost::mutex::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::mutex'

I have searched about the issue and it seems that copy constructor in kd-tree is protected and class is non copyable. I tried using pointers it works, but problem in my case is that I am not able to access data out of function block:

```
std::vector<SpatialTree*> cloudTrees(pointCloudPath.size()); 

for(int i = 0; i < pointCloudPath.size(); i++) 
{ 
        readPLY(pointCloudPath.at(i), pointClouds.at(i));   
        SpatialTree cloud1tree(pointClouds.at(i).begin(), pointClouds.at(i).end()); 
        cloudTrees.at(i) = &cloud1tree; 
}   

 //data in cloudTrees is not accessible
```

Any help please, how can I copy tree in my vector ?

Comment: Try something like `cloudTrees[i].insert(pointClouds.at(i).begin(), pointClouds.at(i).end());` in your loop.

Comment: @sloriot Thanks for the idea. I changed vector with array and inserted the cloudtree values instead, and it worked :)

Comment: This is more a C++ question than a cgal question. In the first case, you want: `std::vector<SpatialTree> cloudTrees; cloudTrees.reserve(...);` then `cloudTrees.emplace_back(pointClouds.at(i).begin(), pointClouds.at(i).end());`. In the second case, you want `cloudTrees.at(i) = new SpatialTree(...);`.

Comment: Hey Marc, thanks for your comment. There is no copy constructor in cgal kd-tree available as public. I tried only by mentioning: std::vector<SpatialTree> cloudTrees; followed by reserve, I get error: 

'CGAL::Kd_tree<SearchTraits,Splitter_,UseExtendedNode>::Kd_tree' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CGAL::Kd_tree<SearchTraits,Splitter_,UseExtendedNode>'

and on resizing I get same error as I mentioned in my question. Although using second approach, adding element in vector and initializing using new SpatialTree(..) it worked

Comment: Ah, right, Kd_tree is not movable (its destructor also looks questionable), so it cannot easily be used in a std::vector (there are proposals to make that possible in some future C++ revision, but nothing done yet). Ideally someone would make Kd_tree movable...